# AWS Crossaccount - Parameters Store / Secrets Manager access to parameters in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

I'm wondering if something is possible at all, or I'm trying to build something that is not possible from the start.

Let's say within Account A there is an RDS DB Password, (can be any AWS resource ID or value) that I have stored in Secrets Manager or Parameter Store.

Now I want to use that value in AWS CDK in Account B, is this possible?

It is possible to retrieve the value based on ARN, see: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/get-secrets-manager-values-aws-cdk#get-secrets-manager-value-by-arn---alternative but would this work cross-account?

Comment: With this answer(update) it is possible to do this just by sharing Paramters between account

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78052099/13126651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a policy to your secret granting access to other AWS account. Check https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secrets-manager-share-between-accounts/